Why are there guns & bombs in the Feudal Era on Inuyasha?
Hmmmm..... Why are there guns & bombs in the Feudal Era on Inuyasha?
Guns & Bombs (from Inuyasha)




Resources - From here.
There are no guns or bombs in the Feudal Era or in the Medieval Era, are there?
I know Technology can progress differently in fantasy worlds, but doesn't that seem anachronistic?
Like these examples on TV tropes https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnachronismStew
Plus, it's really hard to imagine how technology progresses in Medieval Fantasy worlds and High Fantasies, isn't it? So how exactly can Technology progress differently in the Medieval Era (or Middle Ages)?


There are no guns or bombs in the Feudal Era or in the Medieval Era, are there?

Yes there were.
Matchlock guns were invented in 1411 and introduced to Japan by the Portuguese in 1543. The guns seen in the first two screenshots are a specific type of matchlock gun called the tanegashima, which was widely used during the Sengoku era. The six-barreled gun in the third screenshot looks like a volley gun, which was also a 15th-century invention; I'm unsure whether these were also used during the Sengoku era but it's entirely possible.
Handheld bombs of the type depicted in the fourth screenshot have been in use since the 11th century; the Mongols used them during their 13th-century invasion of Japan. Again, I'm unsure how widespread their use was during the Sengoku era, but they're definitely not anachronistic; the Japanese would have known how to build them.
Rather than Anachronism Stew, I would chalk this up to another trope: Reality is Unrealistic. The common perception of Sengoku-era samurai is that they only used swords, so seeing them use anything else can look anachronistic, even if they actually did use gunpowder weapons quite extensively.
